# Installing Z-Wave Device Applications

Tags: visual-studio-2013, dashboard, home-automation, z-wave

I am curious about the Lab of Things and i've just started to learn it.
I am studying it in the network lab of my university. We have a z-wave controller stick, 2 on/off switch, 1 dimmer receiver and 1 sensor.
To set and run the platform, i followed the instructions in this link below:
http://www.lab-of-things.com/GettingStartedLoT_Beta1.pdf
While running the source code and adding a z-wave device, I faced an annoying problem here.
After adding the z-wave driver and running the code i saw 4 different device on the dashboard, it looks like below:

[image]

I tried to install these nodes and applications but apps are not installed. I think that's why i get an error message like below when i run the platform:

[image]

I searched on the internet for this error and i found a discussion like this error but i couldn't apply the solution. In this discussion they say that the applications (alerts, sensor, lights etc.) should be compiled seperately. I tried to do it but Visual Studio still gives the same error. 
Here is the link of discussion that i found on the internet:
https://labofthings.codeplex.com/discussions/476781
All answers will be appreciated.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by following these instructions which are written in this link:

https://labofthings.codeplex.com/discussions/476781

" For starters, it looks from the screenshot posted on stackoverflow that you have broken configuration at this point—the access control rules (in output\configs\config\rules.xml) have a reference to module Alerts but that module is not listed in output\configs\config\modules.xml

To fix the config, 1) run reset.bat, which will reset your configuration to default; or 2) fix it manually if you think you understand the semantics.

Then, make sure that the apps you want to use are compiled. Their binaries should show up in output\binaries\pipeline\addin\homeos.hub.apps.alerts.

Then, go through the setup process again, and things should work at this point in time.

A little more on this: we have confirmed that broken configuration will occur when app binaries are not found. We will post a bug fix soon, but for now, the remedy in my original response (reset, compile, then install device) should work. Let us know if you are still seeing issues. "

I hope this would be helpful for someone.